# Sorting redirect to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I was using `SortExpression="fieldName"` to sort my `GridView`'s columns.
And was working perfect ! But now when I click on the `column's header´ it redirect to another page... And no matter wich column I try to sort, it redirect always to the same page. I don't know what it could be. Any clue? 
Here's my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif" 
            DataKeyNames="id"
            CssClass="gridview" DataSourceID="MyDataSource"
            AllowSorting ="True" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#CCCCCC" 
            BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="GrayText"
            CellPadding="1"
            CellSpacing="5"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
            ForeColor = "Black" RowStyle-CssClass="gridview" 
            onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">            
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <columns>

                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="id"  />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PRIORIDADE" DataField="prioridade" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="SITUAÇÃO"  DataField="situacao" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="RESPONSAVEL" DataField="responsavel" HeaderStyle-Width="65px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="65px" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DATA DE CADASTRO" DataField="dt_cadastro" SortExpression="dt_cadastro" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderStyle-Width="60px"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                    <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PREVISÃO DE TÉRMINO" DataField="previsao_termino" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderStyle-Width="60px"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PROJETO" DataField="projeto"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FUNCIONALIDADE" DataField="funcionalidade" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CLUBE" DataField="clube"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="70px" HeaderText="VISUALIZAR" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Btn_Visualizar" runat="server" Text="VISUALIZAR" CssClass="Btn_Grid"  Font-Size="7pt" Font-Names="Verdana, Arial"  OnClick="Btn_Visualizar_Click"
                            CommandName="visualizar" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" />                            
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="66px" HeaderText="ALTERAR">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Btn_Alterar" runat="server" Text="ALTERAR" CssClass="Btn_Grid" Font-Size="7pt" Font-Names="Verdana, Arial"
                            CommandName="editar" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                </columns>
            <EditRowStyle ForeColor="Black" CssClass="GridViewEditRow" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />      
            </asp:GridView>
```

RowwCommand:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "visualizar")
            {
                Session["id"] = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString())].Cells[0].Text;
                Session["editar"] = null;
            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "editar")
            {
                Session["id"] = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString())].Cells[0].Text; //Grava o ID do chamado da linha correspondente.
                Session["editar"] = 1; // 1 - Editar   2 - Não Editar .
            }

            Response.Redirect("/Adm/DetalhesChamado.aspx");

        }
```

Obs: As you can see I have a `Button` (`Btn_Alterar`) that redirect to another page, when I click to sort the column, i'm redirect to the same page. I don't know if there's something to do with it...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably,that's a postback.coz of `onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"`

Comment: Hi @TamalKantiDey. I'll make some changes to test it and as soon as possible i'll leave a feedback. Tell me, how could i work over it?

Comment: It will be better if u provide the `GridView1_RowCommand` code.

Answer (score 0):

The postback is because of `onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand`.

When a `onrowcommand` is attached to `GridView` it will surly fired when you click on it. try to remove the event or update code accordingly.